# Can Solr perform geo-spacial searches on WKT?

Tags: solr

Solr can perform certain [geo-spacial searches](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch) on its data. Can it index WKT in order to perform these geo-spacial searches?

I do not necessarily need to perform the query with a WKT string. What I do need is the ability to provide WKT in my Solr documents for indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Lucene/Solr 4 (trunk, not officially released) with the new Lucene spatial module and JTS support, which handles the WKT / polygons.  The Solr component of this is still pending.  You'll see some reference to all this at [Spatial4j.com](https://github.com/spatial4j/spatial4j)  You'll have to do a little digging yourself on how its done but it works.  Dateline and pole wrap are not yet supported for WKT/polygons.